# write in array format in fortran

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran90, gfortran

I try to write an output file.dat with an *nxn* matrix format .

I write the code but the output is a column of value f.

Now the problem is: how can i change the output-format of the file to write?

from:
 1
 2
 4
 5
 ...

to: 1,2,3,4 //
    5,6,8,.. //

```
program eccen
    implicit none
    integer, parameter:: grid=800
    integer::i,j,k,n,m
    real*8,allocatable::f(:,:)
    real*8::xx(grid),yy(grid),mval,Mxval
    real*8,allocatable::x(:),y(:)

    open(10,file='3d_disk.txt')
    n=0
        DO
                READ(10,*,END=100)
                n=n+1
        END DO

 100     continue
        rewind(10)

    allocate(x(n),y(n))

    do i=1, n
        read(10,*) x(i),y(i)
    end do


    mval=-20.
    Mxval=20.
    do i=1, grid
        xx(i) = mval + ((Mxval - mval)*(i-1))/(grid-1)
        yy(i) = mval + ((Mxval - mval)*(i-1))/(grid-1)
    end do

    open(20,file='3d_map.dat')

    allocate(f(n,n))
    f=0
    do i=1,grid
        do j=1,grid
            m=0.
            do k=1, n
                if (x(k) > xx(i) .and. x(k) < xx(i+1) .and. &
                 & y(k) > yy(j) .and. y(k) < yy(j+1)) then  
                    m=m+1 ! CONTA IL NUMERO DI PARTICELLE
                end if
            end do
            f(i,j)=float(m+1)
```

I thing that the modification must be here from this:

```
                write(20,*) f(i,j)
            end do
            write(20,*)
     print *,i
        end do    
end program eccen
```

to:

```
    do i=1,grid
      do j=1,grid
        write(20,*) f(i,j)
      end do
    end do

end do
            write(20,*)
     print *,i
        end do

 end program eccen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement

```
write(20,*) f(i,j)
```

will write the value of `f(i,j)` then move to the next line, so the file you're getting is exactly what your code is specifying.  If you want the file to contain `n` rows each with `n` values try

```
write(20,*) f(i,:)
```

which ought to make a good stab at writing the whole of row `i` of the array to a single line in the output file.  Of course, this makes your loop over `j` redundant so you can remove it.

Comment: You'd need to use an explicit format (rather than list directed) to avoid the processor inserting arbitrary line breaks (starting new records) where it sees fit while executing a particular write statement.