# Arranged array in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

```
Program allo
  Implicit none
  integer :: A,ok,i,B,k
  Real, Dimension (:,:), Allocatable :: note

  Print*, "enter line A"
  Read*, A
  Print*, "enter range B"
  Read* ,B

  Allocate (note(A,B), STAT=ok)
  If (ok/=0) then 
    print*, "failed"
    STOP
  end if

  Do i=1,A
    Do k=1,B    
      Read*, note(i,k)
    End do
  End do

  print*,shape(note, /A,B/)

  Deallocate (note) 
End Program allo
```

When I compile it normally without the "shape" option, it gives me an array on 1 line, I want to have the (A,B) array. I tried to shape it to have my perfect table but it gives me error.

Comment: Do you want to print the array in multiple lines?

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting the code and putting it into a code block. Please roll back if you disagree to my changes.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Thank you for reformatting it, i'm new here. Yes exactly, as it is allocated.

Comment: Please edit your question to make this more clear, then. I guessed right this time, but you should make sure that your question is easily understood.

Comment: You are asking about [formatting nicely a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16654249/3157076)?  There are several other questions on this topic if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`shape`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SHAPE.html) intrinsic returns the shape of your array, here the result will be an array `[ A, B ]`.

What you are trying to do is reshaping the array, for which you need to use the [`reshape`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RESHAPE.html) intrinsic. 
However, the array is already in the desired shape. It is just not printed that way.

I would propose a loop to print the array:

```
  do i=1,A
    print *, note(i,:)
  enddo !i
```